# I can't get the value of length-1 working and also can't update the array using simple array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java, in the below code what I tried to achieve is to set the first index as a number, second index as the same number, 3rd index is addition of first and second index in an array and then tried to add last three index from the array and add this number to existing array, but don't know why length-1 doesn't work for, I will appreciate any help.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
    
            int [] arr = new int[10];
            int number = 10;
            arr[0] = number;
            arr[1] = number;
            arr[2] = number + number;

            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
                arr[i + 3] = arr[arr.length -1] + arr[arr.length -2] + arr[arr.length -3];

            }
            for(int j =0; j < arr.length; j++){
                System.out.print("\t" + arr[j]);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error is  " + e);
        }


    }
}
```

> this is the output i m getting
> 10  10  20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> but expected out put is
> 10  20  30  50  80  160 290  and so on

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: "*... but don't know why length-1 doesn't work...*" - This is quite unspecific. Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post and add expected and observed output.

Comment: i want to have some thing like this, [4, 4, 8, 16], so started with an empty array then i have added number to index0, same number to index1, addition of that number to index2. so after that i have run the for loop to assign numbers to rest of the indexes, but i can't achieve this with the above code .

Comment: "expected out put is 10 20 30 50 80 160 290", do you mean 10 10 20 30 because you've told the first two positions to be 10 so I'm not sure how the second one becomes 20.

Answer (score 2):

You start by setting your array to be:

```
10 10 20 X ... 0
```

Your loop is doing the following:

Set the X = (length -1) +(length-2). However, at the time of running the loop the last entry in the array is not 20 and 10 but 0 and 0 because length is 10 (for 10 digits in the array). Therefore you are always referring to the last two digits in the array.

If I understand your desired output. You can solve that by changing it to:

```
        arr[i + 3] = arr[i+2] + arr[i+1] + arr[i];
```

Comment: Glad that worked out for you @isfan